# A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo uma coluna chamada `produtodata` que possui o seguinte formato datetime:

```
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Preciso filtrar os registros que estão entre a data '2019-06-26 00:00:00.000' até hoje.

Tentei algo como:

```
SELECT produtodata, * FROM PRODUTO WHERE PRODUTODATA BETWEEN CAST('2019-06-26 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2019-09-09 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
```

Porém eu recebo:

> A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime
>   resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.

Também tentei sem o CAST, mas recebo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tem certeza de que é MySQL?!

Comment: @José Diz sql, tag alterada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tal mensagem de erro está sendo emitida é porque a coluna PRODUTODATA está declarada como texto (varchar(*n*), por exemplo). Neste caso é necessário saber qual é o formato em que a data está armazenada, pois pode ser "aaaa-mm-dd", "dd/mm/aaaa", "mm/dd/aaaa" dentre vários formatos disponíveis. Pelo trecho "1753-01-01 00:00:00.000" do enunciado me parece que é "aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm".

```
-- código #1
declare @DataInicial datetime, @DataFinal datetime;
set @DataInicial= convert (datetime, '26/6/2019', 103);   -- dd/mm/aaaa
set @DataFinal= convert (datetime, '9/9/2019', 103);      -- dd/mm/aaaa

SELECT produtodata, * 
  from PRODUTO 
  where convert (datetime, PRODUTODATA, 121) between @DataInicial and @DataFinal;
```

O código acima é *[non sargable](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)*.

Comment: No código # 1 acima deve-se substituir *convert (datetime, PRODUTODATA, 121)* por `PRODUTODATA`, tornando então o predicado sargable.

Answer (score 2):

Como meu sql estava em português, foi necessário rodar este comando:

```
set dateformat ymd
```

Depois disso a consulta funcionou.